# Alert users when a notice is added to their post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-abilities, post-notices

Moderators have the ability to add notices to a post if something needs to be addressed. For example:

[image: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for more information.]

These are handy, but don't notify the owner of the post they're applied to, so there's almost no chance the user will see it and actually be able to make the requested change. Mods end up needing to leave a comment, which defeats the point of the post notice in the first place. Can post notices that are meant to be addressed (citation needed, insufficient explanation, etc.) add an inbox notification so the user has a chance to actually address them?

Comment: a capital idea! Remember when I said 90% of community feedback wasn't, uh, [so hot](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html)? This is the ten percent!

Comment: Great suggestion.  I keep seeing feature requests like this lately that I thought of but never posted.  I need to get more up-in-arms about things!

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I would expect to happen.

Comment: @JeffAtwood between twitter and here ... you're worrying me. Are you ok sir?

Comment: You mean *it doesn't already do this*? Wow, I've used the feature and just expected that it did... Whoops.

Comment: @CodyGray So did I; we just did a test a few minutes ago to find out

Comment: @CodyGray I was a little surprised it didn't too. Michael volunteered to be a lab rat, I placed a notice, no notification.

Comment: The particular notice in the screenshot doesn't affect the owner of the question it's attached to, though; it affects the answerers. So this may not be necessary for every notice.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky - But is that specific notice placed on a specific answer, or is it placed on the entire question? The former makes sense (as would the corresponding notification), whereas the later really wouldn't since it's true for all questions (hopefully).

Comment: @David: You have a point, but I suspect it might be a good idea to notify the owner anyway. They might still be interested, and even if not, it's at worst a very minor annoyance.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky In this case it was attached to a specific answer; post notices aren't just for questions

Comment: @jcolebrand, withdrawal symptoms. Or maybe twin-induced lack of sleep :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Users will now get inbox messages for the "citation" and "content dispute" post notices.

Both of these are "actionable" notices, so it makes sense for the post owner to be informed.  None of the other standard post notices really call for the owner to do anything (they're mostly answer focused), so notices will not be generated for them.

It's possible we'll add some new notice types that also result in notification.

Comment: What if the "we are looking for long answers" notice (whatever it's actually called) is added to an answer? Could the answer's author be notified?

Comment: @AnnaLear That'd be nice; that's the one that actually started this

Comment: @Anna - sure, that makes sense.  Next build.

Comment: FWIW "Insufficient explanation" notices (is that the "we are looking for long answers" notice?) on [codereview.se] are also actionnable by the author of an answer, and they don't trigger a notification [and this has caused useless frictions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6888/23788). What happened to the *next build*?

Comment: @KevinMontrose can you please enable notifications for the "insufficient explanation" and "insufficient justification" notice types on Code Review? Is there a process where we can track progress on this rather then pinging you here every few months?