# What is the meaning of "Notice added Redditted by ..."?

Tags: support, post-notices, reddit

I was going through the [Revisions of a particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14415881/revisions) and one of the events mentioned:

> **Notice added** Redditted by Shog9♦

See the image for yourself:

[image: Redditted Notice]

What does this particular notice mean? Does it by any chance has anything to do with [reddit, the front page of the internet](http://www.reddit.com/)? If so, what is the relation? And if it has been actually submitted to reddit, then who submitted it and where is the link to it?

Moreover, I guess only diamond moderators are capable of adding this notice. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The following question doesn't state anything about this particular notice:

- [What are these notices under my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That socks question [was reddited](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/16x9a3/how_to_pair_socks_from_a_pile_efficiently/) a few months ago. Because of the nature of the question, the attention it got resulted in a LOT of off-topic comments and answers.

It was so bad that Shog put up the following notice to try to stem that flow of off-topic comments and answers.

[image]

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/16y0as/til_that_redditors_going_to_stack_overflow_and/)

---

FWIW, the socks question currently has 62 answers, 40 of which are deleted.

Comment: That TIL post on reddit was posted so that this question could have been answered properly with evidence along with a nice image of the notice :)

Answer (score 5):

Ah, the infamous socks question.

Yes, the "reddited" notice is one of the notices mentioned in the question you linked to, and it serves the same purpose as the [other notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172592/162704):

> Post notices are short text boxes that are attached to posts in order to annotate some exceptional situation. They allow ♦ moderators or bounty donors to let other users know something about the post outside of the normal channels of edits, votes, comments and answers.

It's only available on Stack Overflow, and I'm not sure if it's available to moderators, I think it's employee-only. And as you've already guessed, the exceptional situation the notice addresses is that the question hit the front page of reddit/r/programming or other similarly high traffic link sharing sites (I'm looking at you, Hacker News), and as a result it has attracted a *lot* of visitors from outside StackVerse.

As you probably already noticed, the question generated a couple (or more) close / re-open wars. I don't know why Shog9 applied the notice when he did, but to me it read a bit like:

> Hey all, lots of eyes on the question right now, can we please stop changing its state every few minutes? We're starting to appear a bit foolish to outsiders. Kthnxbai!

Also, there were *a lot* of off topic comments, both on the question and its answers, and more than a couple joke answers. Meta commentary, side discussions, good jokes, bad jokes, etc, get tiring after a while.

Comment: Yeah. *Usually* it isn't such a problem. But the socks question was unique since it was controversial to begin with.

Comment: @Mysticial Heh, controversial doesn't even begin to describe it. There was an almost immediate Meta discussion, tons and tons of comments, the visible re-open/close wars, joke answers, and a lengthy discussion in the mod only chat room, where I was trying to convince people that the question is horribly off topic for SO (so I can steal it for Programmers ;)

Comment: @Yannis: ***I was trying to convince people that the question is horribly off topic for SO (so I can steal it for Programmers).*** I was about to suggest you [Politics.SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com/), but I see that you are a moderator yourself over there. The community seems to have made a right choice :-)