# Allow Post Notices to be Community-Customized Like Off-Topic Close Reasons on SE Network Sites

Tags: feature-request, post-notices

In their infinite wisdom, SE made it possible for each community to pick its own off-topic close reasons, recognizing that not every community has the same guidelines. The same wisdom should be applied to post notices. Post notices should be allowed to be customized by the moderators in each community to allow proper moderation of answers.

Currently there are 6 default post-notices that are universal across the network. While some of these (bounty notices, locked message) are good and universal across the sites, some of them aren't. And some good messages are missing for certain sites that may not be applicable to all the others.

Here is the current list of post notices as I understand them. This list should be allowed to be customized by each community within reason (the universal ones, like bounties and locks, should be kept).

- **Wiki Answer**

  > This question's answer is a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit to improve it! *No additional answers can be added here*
- **citation needed**

  > This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.
- **current event**

  > Post is related to a rapidly changing event.
- **insufficient explanation**

  > We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain *why* you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more information.
- **bounty**

  > This question has an open bounty worth +X reputation from [user] ending in [time].

  or

  > This question had a bounty worth +X reputation from [user] that ended [time] ago; grace period ends in 23 hours
- **locked**

  > This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended discussions, please use chat.

<sup>Note: I am not a moderator, so I cannot confirm that these are accurate. I took them from [this faq-proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post) which should also be updated if these are not accurate</sup>