# Post notices don't show up on mobile website

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, post-notices

I'm using iOS chrome.

I tried to add a post notice to [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19444/which-is-more-common-to-use-correct-please-the-following-sentences/19447#19447) earlier, but I couldn't see the notice. I refreshed a few times and it still wasn't there. I asked someone on a computer to check and make sure the notice went through, and they could see it. It would be nice to be able to see them on mobile, or at least get some kind of success confirmation. Makes phone modding a bit difficult. :)

Comment: Showing those notices is important for non-mods, too.  I just ran into this (wait, did someone remove the notice? I don't see an edit), and later learned it was the mobile site, not the post, that was to blame.

Comment: @monica Agreed! But it's especially counterintuitive to not see it after you're the one that just created it moments before ;). I was verrrry confused. (Though, I think high rep users can add post notices too? Maybe. I forget.)

Comment: Only moderators can add post notices. There's a feature request here somewhere to allow high-rep users to do so (via voting, not unilaterally), which would help some sites a lot.

Comment: Here is [the feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224763/) that @Monica mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime in the distant past this was fixed.