# hiding discussions originating from religion.SE from the "hot-network-question" list on scientific SE websites

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Here I mention only hiding from hard-science SE websites : maths, phsycis, chemistry, earth science, etc. And I explained why with a simple and verifiable argument :

**religions are considered anti-scientific (the opposite of science) by so many professional scientists**

recall that many of those websites are mainly used by **professionnal researchers**, the same people who answered to those famous surveys on religions.

---

Given that religions are considered anti-scientific (the opposite of science) by so many professional scientists,

wouldn't it be a good idea to hide from the "hot-network-questions" the  discussions originating from [christianity.stackexchange](http://christianity.stackexchange), [buddhism.stackexchange](http://christianity.stackexchange) or [hinduism.stackexchange](http://christianity.stackexchange)

when we are on one of those [highly-scientific stackexchange websites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science) ?

And isn't there a huge bias in favour of downvotes here ? Even if you don't agree, the question isn't "stupid" nor "crazy".

Comment: @PeterJ : I mentionned only scientific SE websites, and I explained why with a simple and verifiable argument.

Comment: @user1952009 In regard to the last paragraph... You should read [voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @Robert Longson : ok so scientists HATE religions (the surveys say that), but don't agree with me ? come on... the bias is that you are english/american natives, that's all.

Comment: @user1952009 I'm explaining that people who are downvoting may well not think your post is either stupid or crazy since you didn't seem to understand the way **this** site works.

Comment: @Robert Longson : I don't care how meta works (why would I ???), I am on maths.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user1952009 And yet you posted here and not [meta maths stackexchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/) so you're subject to the rules here and not maths rules. Perhaps you should remove the last paragaph of your question since it doesn't seem to be part of your main question premise.

Comment: @Robert Longson : be honest, you know that this has nothing to do on meta.maths, this is a general subject. so this is one more bias : the people on meta are not the same as on maths

Comment: I haven't stated an opinion either way as to where the question should be, I've merely explained the way this particular site works to someone who seemed not to understand it.

Comment: @JakeGould : ok very funny. you don't understand that it is insulting to say "you are a scientist and proud to belong to one of the world most important scientist community but you'll have to accept that religions are also there, on YOUR website". if I was a drug addict, I wouldn't like that cops would come on MY website, and the converse is also true. that's the same here.

Comment: What famous survey are you preaching about in such a religious fashion?

Comment: @user1952009: Whether you're likening scientists to cops and religious people to druggies or the other way around, most people in both groups would be taken aback by the comparison, if not insulted... even if they got the notionally better end of it.

Comment: @user1952009 You've made a lot of assertions with no evidence to back them up. For instance you could have created a question on meta maths asking whether your fellow maths folk would like to see this change. If it gots lots of upvotes then you'd know that that's the case rather than guessing. Wouldn't that be the "scientific" way to do things? Scientists expect to be challenged all the time to prove what they say and they don't in general think that is either insulting or that the challenger is necessarily biased.

Answer (score 11):

I don't understand why this is a problem.

You've made a couple assumptions in your question that are, actually, borderline insulting:

1. That  scientifically-minded individuals can't have beliefs or religious practices.
2. That scienficially-minded individuals have a proclivity to interrupt and disrupt religious beliefs with science.
3. That scienficially-minded individuals can't ask neutral, honest questions about religion.

And even if someone *does* start trolling a religious SE site, that simply warrants suspension.

I've never heard of this being a problem on Stack Exchange before, though, and I see no reason to make a change to prevent a behavior which, if it were going to happen, we would have seen years ago.

Comment: the problem is that there are so many scientific researchers and teachers FIGHTING religions EVERYDAY !!! go to school !!!! you'll understand what I mean....

Comment: @user1952009 that seems to be counter to the position you assert in the question. Such researchers and teachers would both frequent scientific sites and want to see hot religious questions so they can continue their fight.

Comment: @Robert Longson : no you missed the most important point, scientists fight religions by talking about science, not religion nor philosophy nor history. for example, a scientist would ask for a scientific definition of god/religion/believing, which would make religion a science question, hence many answers could be simple, rigourous, constructive and definitve : the opposite of religion/philosphy

Answer (score 10):

Well why stop at the religion sites, then?  Serious scientists also shouldn't be distracted by questions about science fiction or movies or martial arts or gaming or anime or... whoa, this is getting complicated.

Maybe it's better to trust the members of your communities to skip questions they're not interested in.  *Most* of the Hot Network Questions list is uninteresting to most people; it's there at all because *sometimes* a question will be interesting to the reader -- an unusual tie-in with your site, maybe, but more likely, a question about *some other interest* that the person has.  Most people are not so focused that they'll *never* be interested in something from outside their usual stomping grounds, after all.  At least not the scientists I know.

Comment: you don't understand that religions are anti-scientific. it is an intellectual fight. science and religion are antagonists, this is not a game nor a distraction

Comment: I know plenty of people who are able to function in both religious and scientific contexts without fights breaking out.  You're making a pretty broad statement there -- *all* religions are *always* anti-scientific?  Really?  Sure, some are anti-science on certain points in ways that provoke fights and have political impact, but (a) those guys don't represent everybody and (b) those issues are a tiny, tiny part of the whole.

Comment: @JakeGould : not saying everybody understand and care about that antagonism, just saying a majority of scientists do and live it (the surveys...)

Comment: @JakeGould : your american way to think, that everything is acceptable to say or think, that it is liberty. but no, schools are to make people smarter, and only smart things are allowed there. a scientific website is a kind of school for adults. and yes, cops are forbidden in rave party (that's not for nothing) in the same way that drug addicts are forbidden in cops meetings ---> people should not always mix and tolerate each other.