# Who tags/provide labels to question?

Tags: support, moderators, post-notices

Recently my question got labeled as - 'Post is related to a rapidly changing event.'

who does decide such tags and labels ?

[Here is my question link](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/can-we-see-the-russian-progress-59-spacecraft-burn-up-on-reentry/9043#9043)

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those notices are typically added by the elected diamond moderators on a site, although I imagine Stack Exchange community managers and some other employers could add them. If you press the "edited ... hours ago" on your question you'll see it was added by [TildalWave♦](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/49/tildalwave).