# Sorting and filtering posts with notices

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, post-notices

Posts that have post notices can be seen on `https://<site>.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed`. This includes [posts that have notice types](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165006/260388) "Citation Needed", "Insufficient Explanation", etc., and also includes bounty notices.

"Citation Needed" post notices (example below) are often used by sites that insist on answers being backed up with authoritative references.

> Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.

I want to filter the posts that have notices by specific notice types, e.g "Citation Needed". I also want to sort them by newest/oldest since sometimes such unsourced posts require action.

Comment: AFAIK this can be done in SEDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/873471/posts-with-active-notices?PostNoticeTypeId=1) will do that for you; feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/fork/query/873471/) it to suit your needs.

[image]

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT n.PostId AS [Post Link],
  n.CreationDate AS 'Notice added',
  p.CreationDate AS 'Post created'
  FROM PostNotices AS n
  INNER JOIN Posts AS p ON n.PostId = p.Id
  WHERE n.PostNoticeTypeId = ##PostNoticeTypeId:int?1## -- 1 = Citation Needed
    AND n.DeletionDate IS NULL
  ORDER BY p.CreationDate ASC
```

SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday morning, so some notices might have been removed already.