# Notes to the author are displayed publicly

Tags: discussion, post-notices

[This concise answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200628/how-to-create-an-integer-array-within-a-recursion#answer-17200670) has a notice visible at the bottom:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context...

Shouldn't that notice be visible only to the person that posted the answer? The message has little relevance to anyone else.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, post notices are meant to be public. They are not only there to inform the post author that their answer is somehow problematic, but also every future reader and potential editor of the answer.

Other than the "long answers" one, we have a couple more notices that would appear similarly:

- **citation needed**

  This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.
- **current event**

  Post is related to a rapidly changing event.

These notices can be applied and removed by diamond moderators. A couple of related Meta questions:

- [What are these notices under my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post)
- [Alert users when a notice is added to their post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125457/alert-users-when-a-notice-is-added-to-their-post)

Comment: *but also every future reader of the answer.*  and potential editor

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Hopefully a potential editor would read the post before they edit it, thus also becoming a reader. That said, I don't know if that's actually true in these dark days of robo-reviewing.

Comment: :) Yes editors should read the post, but I meant that the message might induce me to edit the answer. For example if I knew why appending returning none is a problem I would add that explination.

Comment: That... makes sense. Added it to the answer.